# Compare each value of a column with the rest using SQL in Excel

Tags: sql, excel, vba, ado

I'm just getting started with SQL and right now I'm facing a problem. I already did a Query which gives me a table that contains the x coordinate of a point, the y coordinate of the same point, it's location and the name of that point (each of this group a values are allocated in a different column)
So:

**Point_name/X_coord/Y_coord/Location**

Location has 3 possible values (top, bottom and not allocated)

I need to take the coordinate of each point (both X and Y) and compare it with the coordinates of the other points as long as they are in the same location.

If the distance between coordinates is below a certain value I must calculate the distance between matching points where distance is:

*sqrt((x2-x1)^2 + (y2-y1)^2)*

The name, coordinates adn location of both points must be outputed in a different table whith the following columns

**Point_name1/X_coord1/X_corrd1/Point_name2/X_coord2/Y_coord2/Location**

My first approach was doing an Excel Macro but it takes way to long considering I have more than 50k points so I thought that I could use SQL in excel using an ADO connection but I don't know how to solve this, could you guys help me out even if it's just pointing me towards the appropriate method?. It must be done in excel using ADO that's one of the constrains of what I'm doing.

Dataset example: (Input table)

```
| Point_name | X_Coord  | Y_coord |   Location    |


| A          | 18886.2  | 1852.2  | TOP           |

| B          | 11071.21 | 3507.47 | TOP           |

| C          | 11138.81 | 3429.47 | TOP           |

| D          | -15.63   | -10     | BOTTOM        |

| E          | -35      | -32     | BOTTOM        |

| F          | 13.23    | 45.6    | NOT ALLOCATED |

| G          | 18935    | 1820    | NOT ALLOCATED |

| H          | 18935    | 1785    | NOT ALLOCATED |
```

Expected table: (considering a distance less than 36)

```
| Point_name1 | X_coord1 | Y_coord1 | Point_name2 | X_coord2 | Y_coord2 | Distance |   Location    |

| D           | -15.63   |      -10 | E           |      -35 |      -32 | 29.312   | BOTTOM       |

| G           | 18935    |     1820 | H           |    18935 |     1785 | 35       | NOT ALLOCATED |
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: It would help if you could provide a sample dataset which would be sufficient for small-scale testing. I'm guessing you could implement this in SQL by aliasing your table twice  e.g. `select a.Name, a.location,  {distance calc here} as dist  from [input] a, [input] b where A.location=B.location and A.name != B.Name and {distance calc here} < [threshold here]`   You could save some processing by skipping the square root in the distance calculation and squaring the distance threshold in the SQL.

Comment: should be `select a.Name, b.Name a.location, ...`

Comment: Hi Tim, thanks alot for you insight. I just added some data of both the input and expected tables in the description, I'll try what you just suggested and let you know if it worked :)

Comment: I just finished trying it Tim and I worked perfectly!, the only issue is that since it's comparing the 2 tables it returns D vs E as well as E vs D

Comment: Glad to hear that actually worked.  If you can post your current SQL I might be able to suggest a fix to resolve the duplicates.

Comment: Sure, this is the SQL code I'm using right now:

SELECT a.CLASS AS CLASS_1, a.NET_NAME AS NET_1, a.TP_X AS TP1_X, a.TP_Y AS TP1_Y, b.CLASS AS CLASS_2, b.NET_NAME AS NET_2, b.TP_X AS TP2_X, b.TP_Y AS TP2_Y, Sqr(((a.TP_X-b.TP_X)^2) + ((a.TP_Y-b.TP_Y)^2)) AS DISTANCE, a.TEST_POINT AS LAYER
            FROM `Testpoint_table$` a, `Testpoint_table$` b
            WHERE ((a.TEST_POINT = b.TEST_POINT) AND         (a.NET_NAME <> b.NET_NAME) AND (((a.TP_X-b.TP_X)^2) + ((a.TP_Y-b.TP_Y)^2)) < 1521)

Comment: Does this fix your duplication problem? SELECT a.CLASS AS CLASS_1, a.NET_NAME AS NET_1, a.TP_X AS TP1_X, a.TP_Y AS TP1_Y, b.CLASS AS CLASS_2, b.NET_NAME AS NET_2, b.TP_X AS TP2_X, b.TP_Y AS TP2_Y, Sqr(((a.TP_X-b.TP_X)^2) + ((a.TP_Y-b.TP_Y)^2)) AS DISTANCE, a.TEST_POINT AS LAYER FROM Testpoint_table$ a, Testpoint_table$ b WHERE ((a.TEST_POINT = b.TEST_POINT) AND (a.NET_NAME < b.NET_NAME) AND (((a.TP_X-b.TP_X)^2) + ((a.TP_Y-b.TP_Y)^2)) < 1521)